# Need help creating a macro in Excel with the filename, my name, and the time & date shown

Tags: excel, vba

in excel 2007, how can i create a macro that shows the filename to the left, "prepared by" my name & phone number in the center of the document, and the time & date to the right?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you encountering errors? Please be more specific in your question.

Comment: Is this for **Print Setup** or data in **Worksheet cells??**

Comment: I had a macro that would do it prior to moving over to a Chromebook.  The code was created for me, but now neither the macro or the button is present any longer. :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider:

```
Sub Information()
    Dim s As String
    s = ActiveWorkbook.Name & vbTab & "Prepared by: " & Environ("username") & " 867-5309" & vbTab & Now()
    MsgBox s
End Sub
```

**EDIT#1:**

To place this information into Page Setup, use:

```
Sub qwerty()
    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        .PrintTitleRows = ""
        .PrintTitleColumns = ""
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = ""
    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        .LeftHeader = "&F"
        .CenterHeader = "Prepared by: " & Environ("username") & " 867-5309"
        .RightHeader = "&D  &T"
        .LeftFooter = ""
        .CenterFooter = ""
        .RightFooter = ""
        .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.7)
        .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.7)
        .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
        .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
        .HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
        .FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
        .PrintHeadings = False
        .PrintGridlines = False
        .PrintComments = xlPrintNoComments
        .PrintQuality = 600
        .CenterHorizontally = False
        .CenterVertically = False
        .Orientation = xlPortrait
        .Draft = False
        .PaperSize = xlPaperLetter
        .FirstPageNumber = xlAutomatic
        .Order = xlDownThenOver
        .BlackAndWhite = False
        .Zoom = 100
        .PrintErrors = xlPrintErrorsDisplayed
        .OddAndEvenPagesHeaderFooter = False
        .DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = False
        .ScaleWithDocHeaderFooter = True
        .AlignMarginsHeaderFooter = True
        .EvenPage.LeftHeader.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.CenterHeader.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.RightHeader.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.LeftFooter.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.CenterFooter.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.RightFooter.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.LeftHeader.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.CenterHeader.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.RightHeader.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.LeftFooter.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.CenterFooter.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.RightFooter.Text = ""
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: **Update the post if you need help moving the data into Page Setup.**

Comment: just run the code w/ the username info correctly reflected in vba, right?

Comment: i must've screwed up. i got the macro to appear & everything but when i go to page setup -- nada

Comment: gotta wait 90 minutes to ask another question :-(

Answer (score 0):

To get the filename in a cell, use this formula:

```
=MID(CELL("filename"),SEARCH("[",CELL("filename"))+1, SEARCH("]",CELL("filename"))-SEARCH("[",CELL("filename"))-1)
```

You can add your name and phone to this cell if you need or place it in the adjacent cell.

For the time and date, use:

```
=NOW()
```

Comment: really appreciate the feedback

Comment: if this answered the question, please mark the question as answered so it will not appear in the unanswered section.  thanks.